# How to set custom vite config settings in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, vite, angular17

We would like to configure vite settings in Angular 17 via a `vite.config.js` file or some other way. Specifically, these settings:

```
export default {
  optimizeDeps: {
      disabled: false,
      exclude: [
          'my-third-party-package',
      ],
  },
}
```

Things I have tried but yielded no results:

- Running `ng eject`
- Reading the official documentation on Angular's new build system (https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#esm-default-imports-vs-namespace-imports)
- Creating a `vite.config.js` in the root folder and "hoping" `Angular` picks it up at build time.

Comment: The vite config is internal to the CLI and cannot be modified.

Comment: I created a feature request on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53897

Comment: The request is closed. So how to config vite now?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a custom builder if you must configure vite.

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you serve the app with the new Angular build system, you will have an error like this:

```
typeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module
```

This is because some dependencies are not optimized for Vite.

In order to fix this you must set `optimizeDeps` on your `vite.config.js` but it is **not possible in Angular**.
See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26859

---

I found the next solution:

Inside `angular.json` disable cli cache:

```
"cli": {
  "cache": {
    "enabled": false,
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26345